# Rails 5 custom query in show method with find and where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I apologize for the clumsy question. I have an index method that limits objects to `current_user` and this works great, but I can still access the object in the show method.

**This will only show the current_user objects**

```
def index
  @todo_lists = TodoList.where(user_id: current_user)
end
```

**this unfortunately still allows access to the object if you know the id**

```
def show
  @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id])
end
```

**What I am trying to do but gives `undefined method where` error**

```
def show
  @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:id]).where(user_id: current_user)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should "alternate" your current query. As find returns a single object, the one corresponding to the model/table being asked. While where is intended to be used in the model and it returns an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`, that's what you need to find your TodoList by id.

After that you can use find, which will find a single entity (one record) and return it as an instance of the model.

Try:

```
TodoList.where('user_id = ?', current_user).find(params[:id])
```

Notice, if current_user is an instance of User, assuming it has many products, you can use that association to get all products and then, find the one you need:

```
current_user.todo_lists.find(params[:id])
```